# Нарушает ли hibernate принцип инкапсуляции

Tags: java, hibernate, инкапсуляция

hibernate реализует ORM, может сам создавать новые объекты и приводить типы по своему усмотрению.

Т.к. он может связать ООП и реализационную базу данных, это не может привести к нарушению инкапсуляции java? Ведь реализация должна быть сокрыта а тут нет.

```
@Id
@Column(name= "id")
private Long id;
```

и потом hibernate может редактировать это поле.

я что-то запутался.

Comment: `Ведь реализация должна быть сокрыта а тут нет.` что из реализации тут не сокрыто?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы абсолютно правы, hibernate нарушает принцип инкапсуляции. И даже более того, любая [ORM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM) заставляет нас использовать [POJO классы, которые не имеют ничего общего с инкапсуляцией](https://nvoulgaris.com/how-getters-and-setters-harm-encapsulation/). Тем не менее, есть способ работать с БД, не нарушая принцип инкапсуляции - [sql-speaking-objects](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/12/01/orm-offensive-anti-pattern.html#sql-speaking-objects).

*Я никого ни к чему не призываю, просто есть разные подходы работы с БД.* Однако некоторые программисты могут заметить, что на самом деле POJO классы - это не объекты, это данные, а, значит, там не может нарушатся принципы объектного проектирования. Такое суждение имеет право на жизнь, при таком подходе в программах перемешиваются данные и объекты, работающие с данными, но это уже не имеет ничего общего с ООП, потому что в ОО архитектуре есть только объекты, а данные хранятся всегда внутри объектов и никогда не выглядывают наружу.

Comment: спасибо теперь стало как то намного понятней=)